# AWS Simulation of IAM Policy with {aws:SourceIP} context

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

Given a policy such as

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowedActions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "1.1.1.2/32"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

using the SimulateCustomPolicy call (in this case using boto3) with a context entry such as:

```
{   'ContextKeyName': 'aws:SourceIp',
    'ContextKeyType': 'ip',
    'ContextKeyValues': ['1.1.1.2']}
```

For an action, say 'cloudtrail:DeleteTrail' results in an evaluation of 'implicitDeny' rather than the expected 'allowed'. Is the Context incorrect or incomplete?